# How to fill Array programmatically in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My question is very simple, I have the following array in my angular 5 app:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    galleryImages: NgxGalleryImage[];
}
```

In the example of use for this component they fill like this:

```
this.galleryImages = [
        {
            small: 'assets/1-small.jpg',
            medium: 'assets/1-medium.jpg',
            big: 'assets/1-big.jpg'
        },
        {
            small: 'assets/2-small.jpg',
            medium: 'assets/2-medium.jpg',
            big: 'assets/2-big.jpg'
        },
        {
            small: 'assets/3-small.jpg',
            medium: 'assets/3-medium.jpg',
            big: 'assets/3-big.jpg'
        }
    ];
```

My question is how can I do this myself not manually, if not programmatically?

I try this... but doesn't works:

```
let images:Array<any>= new Array<any>();
    let image:Image= new Image();
    image.small="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/opusclick.com/contract-images/1534437451028-tmp1371670532902548897.jpeg"
    image.medium="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/opusclick.com/contract-images/1534437451028-tmp1371670532902548897.jpeg"
    image.big="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/opusclick.com/contract-images/1534437451028-tmp1371670532902548897.jpeg"
    images.push(JSON.stringify(image));
    this.galleryImages=images;
```

Comment: Why are you using JSON.stringify here ?

Comment: And don't use `new Image` either. It's a plain object.

Comment: create a model which contains (small,big&medium) and put into array

Comment: @Bergi Why should not I use the new .... how do I then initialize the image object and enter its properties?

Comment: @AlejoDev Because it's not an [`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image). Just use an object literal like in the first snippet.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*how can I do this myself not manually, if not programmatically?*" In your second snippet, you still have static data embedded directly in the code, so the known pattern is entirely appropriate (you just have a different number of images and different URIs). If you actually are asking how to make this dynamic, then where does the dynamic data come from and in which format?

Answer (score 0):

If Image is a plain object, the correct way to create your image object is :

```
const images = [];

const image = {
   small: "smallUrl",
   medium: "mediumUrl",
   big: "bigUrl"
};

images.push(image);
this.galleryImages = images;
```

By using JSON.stringify, you are pushing a string to your array instead of an object.

Comment: Why even use `images.push` instead of putting the image directly inside the array literal?

Comment: I just reused its snippet to show him where he was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try by creating an object with type any.

```
let images:Array<any>= new Array<any>();

    images.push({
       small="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/opusclick.com/contract-images/1534437451028-tmp1371670532902548897.jpeg",
       medium="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/opusclick.com/contract-images/1534437451028-tmp1371670532902548897.jpeg",
       big="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/opusclick.com/contract-images/1534437451028-tmp1371670532902548897.jpeg",
    });
    this.galleryImages=images;
```

Answer (score 0):

With new ES feature it can done using spread operator. It will also create a new memory reference for provided array.

```
this.galleryImages = [...[{
   small: "smallUrl",
   medium: "mediumUrl",
   big: "bigUrl"
 }]
]
```